# BadRequestError: cannot use a projection on a property with an equality filter

Tags: google-app-engine

In the snippet of code below when I try to perform these two lines I get this error:"
BadRequestError: cannot use a projection on a property with an equality filter"

```
myname = self.response.get('state')
```

qy1=db.GqlQuery(*SELECT name,phoneNumber,description,city,state FROM Table1 WHERE state =:1",myname)

I do have a for loop after this to iterate through the result set
for i in qy1:
 (do some json dump)
Now the state field is a StringProperty , and even doing str(myname) yields the same results. I have been looking all over they say you should do either what I have done before or to do  state IN 'some string', but if I change it to that I get an error about it not being a list.

Any advice?

full stack trace is :

```
INFO     2013-03-23 14:12:08,756 dev_appserver.py:3103] "POST /sendNearByPlaces.html HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2013-03-23 14:12:22,023 webapp2.py:1552] cannot use projection on a property with an equality filter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\defiant\Desktop\PythonServer\bar.py", line 368, in post
    for i in qy1:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 2326, in next
    return self.__model_class.from_entity(self.__iterator.next())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_query.py", line 2892, in next
    next_batch = self.__batcher.next()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_query.py", line 2754, in next
    return self.next_batch(self.AT_LEAST_ONE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_query.py", line 2791, in next_batch
    batch = self.__next_batch.get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_query.py", line 2528, in __query_result_hook
    self._batch_shared.conn.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_rpc.py", line 1224, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
BadRequestError: cannot use projection on a property with an equality filter
INFO     2013-03-23 14:12:22,075 dev_appserver.py:3103] "POST /sendNearByPlaces.html HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Please post full stacktrace of the exception, I have a feeling that its not failing where you thing it fails.

Comment: i've added the stack trace.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM` is not a projection query. Does you error happen somewhere else where you use `SELECT propertyName FROM`?

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to :
qy1=db.GqlQuery(*SELECT name,phoneNumber,description,city,state FROM Table1 WHERE state =:1",myname)

Comment: and peter, no it does not happen anywhere else

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why properties referenced in an equality (EQUAL) or membership (IN) filter cannot be projected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714386/why-properties-referenced-in-an-equality-equal-or-membership-in-filter-canno)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Projection_Queries) "You cannot project a property that also is referenced in an equality filter. For example SELECT A FROM kind WHERE A = 1 is not supported, but SELECT A FROM kind WHERE B = 1 or SELECT A FROM kind WHERE A > 1 is supported."

[Edit]
In short:

```
qy1=db.GqlQuery(*SELECT name,phoneNumber,description,city,state FROM Table1 WHERE state =:1",myname) # WRONG 
qy1=db.GqlQuery(*SELECT name,phoneNumber,description,city       FROM Table1 WHERE state =:1",myname) # CORRECT
```

[/Edit]

Comment: Documentation moved to here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries#Limitations_on_Projections

Comment: Also, this is an arbitrary rule. I understand there are limitations as projection queries are coming from the index and not the datastore directly, but I can't figure out the reason behind this particular limitation.

Comment: Actually, the link I've provided is the one I wanted you to see... In short what it says is 
qy1=db.GqlQuery(*SELECT name,phoneNumber,description,city,state FROM Table1 WHERE state =:1",myname) is wrong while 

qy1=db.GqlQuery(*SELECT name,phoneNumber,description,city FROM Table1 WHERE state =:1",myname) is correct. 

In a projection query you can't SELECT a property in an equality filter your WHERE clause (in this case "state"). This exactly what the error tells you "BadRequestError: cannot use projection on a property with an equality filter"

See edit

Comment: @Dave this is way too old thread, but it was I doubt I also had. I think the limitation is not technical, it's just because it does not make sense. Why would one fetch a field, that they already know before hand that is equals to "something"? In such cases a keys-only query probably suffices.

Comment: I need to query on a property based on a list of values and then identify which row belongs to which of the list of values. So if I can't add the property in the equality filter in the projection, is my only alternative to do number of queries corresponding to the number of values in the list!?