# Why properties referenced in an equality (EQUAL) or membership (IN) filter cannot be projected?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/projectionqueries

Why a projected query such as this : **SELECT A FROM kind WHERE A = 1** not supported  ?

Comment: Please how exactly what you're trying, with code.

Comment: The reason why is not discussed in any specific documentation taht I have found.  It will have something to do with google's implementation details. If you just researching things try having a look through their various white papers, google IO presentations, maybe something is there.  But either way knowing why won't help you if you really want to do it.  So don't bother with projection queries ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it makes no sense. You are asking

```
SELECT A FROM kind WHERE A = 1
```

so, give me `A` where `A = 1`. Well, you already know that `A = 1`. It makes no sense for DB to allow that.

The `IN` query is internally just a series of equals queries merged together, so the same logic applies to it.

Comment: `A` is a reference number and you want to check your db, which reference number you already know. How to solve this?

Comment: If you only check for existence of entities with certain property value (e.g. `A=1`) the use keys-only query: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Keys_Only_Queries It has the same cost as projection query.

Comment: You are right, if A is my key and not just a unique index in my model. But it's an other topic to decide when should i use own keys or one from "outside". Example: Database for books - A book looks like: (Key, ISBN-10, ISBN-13, OCLC, LCCN), where every column should be unique. Now I've got a list of ISBN-10 that i want to check against my database, to filter what kind of books i'm missing. It would be just nice to have a correct list with only one statement.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning behind this could be that since you already have the values of the properties you are querying you don't need them returned by the query. This is probably a good thing in the long run, but honestly, it's something that App Engine should allow anyway. Even if it didn't actually fetch these values from the datastore, it should add them to the entities returned to you behind the scenes so you can go about your business.

Anyway, here's what you can do...

```
query = MyModel.query().filter(MyModel.prop1 == 'value1', MyModel.prop2 == 'value2)
results = query.fetch(projection=[MyModel.prop3])
for r in results:
  r.prop1 = 'value1'  # the value you KNOW is correct
  r.prop2 = 'value2'
```

Again, would be nice for this to happen behind the scenes because I don't think it's something anybody should ever care about. If I mention a property in a projection list, I'm already stating that I *want* that property as part of my entities. I shouldn't have to do any more computation to get that to happen.

On the other hand, it's just an extra for-loop. :)